# Shared Modules in IntelliJ with LibGDX and Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx

I'm having some trouble setting up a shared module using gradle and LibGDX, using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5. I'm not sure I'm even taking the correct approach. I have three projects: a game, a level editor, and a third for shared code. I want both the game and level editor projects to share the other module. To set this up, I use the [libGDX gradle project setup utility](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle) to create all three projects. The only difference is that I create the shared project without any build targets. I create this using the setup tool because the shared code also depends on libGDX.

Thus my folder structure is:

```
./
     Game/
     Editor/
     Shared/
```

I import the shared project into IntelliJ as I would any other project. Then, in both the Level Editor and Game projects I import the shared project as a module, and add the necessary dependencies for it. This seems to work perfectly for my level editor project, but I run into errors with the game project. It seems to work, as the IDE will not complain about using the imported packages. However, at compile time it says that the package I am importing from the shared project does not exist. Also, when I close/re-open IntelliJ, the projects seem to take the shared module out of the project view (however in module settings, it still exists and I can still set it as a dependency....)

What am I doing wrong here, and am I taking the wrong approach to this?